# speech to text download function

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

Hi can you guys please give me a code to write download function after uploading my audio file for converting to transcript.txt. I need code like I uploaded my audio file into server I see only upload button I can create download button, Can you tell me how to write a code for download function to download that uploaded and converted file from server directly in my web page.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is the text result from your uploaded audio file?  It's in the returned JSON from your upload.

See the [API documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/) for more specifics.

Comment: Yes sir,it's returned json, my view is I need that returned text file in dailog box on my webpage.. I need code   var file = request.files.file;
        var newPath = './public/uploads/' + file.name;

Comment: var insertAttachment = function(file, id, rev, name, value, response) {

            fs.readFile(file.path, function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {

Comment: if (file) {

                        db.attachment.insert(id, file.name, data, file.type, {
                            rev: rev
                        }, function(err, document) {
                            if (!err) {
                                console.log('Attachment saved successfully.. ');

Comment: fs.createReadStream('.flac/.wav').pipe(recognizeStream);                      recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/downloads/transcription.txt'));recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8');
recognizeStream.on('results', function(event) { onEvent('Results:', event); }); recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); }); recognizeStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event);

Comment: });recognizeStream.on('close', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });recognizeStream.on('speaker_labels', function(event) { onEvent('Speaker_Labels:', event); }); function onEvent(name, event) {
 console.log(name, JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

Comment: I have doubt how to store converted converted text file in mongodb